# Empty chain not shown as a choice in selectInput in shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, selectize.js

I want the user of the App to select the text wrappers for some files they must upload. The options are No Wrapper, Double Quotes and Simple Quotes, so I want the `selectInput` function to return `""`, `"\""` or `"'"`, but the first choice does not appear. I show a dummy example:

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  selectInput("quotes","Select Text wrapper", 
              choices= list("None"="","Double Quotes (\")"='"', "Simple Quotes (\')"="'"), 
              selected="'"),
  verbatimTextOutput("value")
))
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input,output){
  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$quotes })
})
```

How to make the `None` choice to appear and to assign an empty character value `""` to `input$quotes`?

Note: I know that it works with `selectize=FALSE`, but I would like to keep the looks of the selectize environment. I also know that you can delete the value and click in the box to get the empty value, but I think this isn't intuitive for the user, I want to have an explicit 'None' choice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does "None"="\"\"" do what you want?

Comment: I want a character of length 0, so "\"\"" does not work (It has two double quote characters in it). `nchar("")`= 0, `nchar("\"\"")`= 2

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: In looking at the code changes made to selectize.js to allow options with no values ot be used as placeholder text, ([here](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/pull/69/files)) it appears that the option with no value takes precedence over an explicit "placeholder" tag. Thus there seems to be no way with the current version of the library (0.10.1) to do this.

So it looks like the selectize.js folks decided that any options with a zero-length string as a value will be used as the placeholder text and not be listed in the input. (See [this](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/issues/68)). This is consistent with the html5 spec for that element. The alternative is that if you set a "placeholder" attribute for the element, it will use that instead. I didn't see a super simple way to set such an element for the select element. I ended up writing this code

```
setPlace <- function(t, p) {
    setattr <- function(x, name, nameval, attr, val) {
        if (!is.null(names(x)) && name %in% names(x) && x[[name]] == nameval) {
            x[[c("attribs",attr)]] <- val
        } else {
            if(is.list(x)) {
                oa <- attributes(x)
                x <- lapply(x, function(z) setattr(z,name, nameval, attr, val))
                attributes(x)<-oa
            }
        }
        x
    }
    setattr(t, "name", "select", "placeholder",HTML(p))
}
```

which will take the HTML returned by selectInput and add the attribute into the element. Then you could use it like

```
setPlace(selectInput("quotes","Select Text wrapper", 
    choices= list("None"="","Double Quotes (\")"='"', "Simple Quotes (\')"="'"), 
    selected="'"), "choose wisely")
```

or something like that in your layout. This will set the placeholder attribute which (since you set a selected value) probably will never be seen. That seemed to work in my tests.

Comment: I'm not sure what the placeholder in the select label does. I've tried your proposal and I get the same result as when I set `selectize=FALSE` in the function `selectInput`, that is, I have the `None` option, but the appearances are not those of the selectize.

Comment: @Rufo What version of the `shiny` package do you have installed? I tested with 0.10.0.

Comment: Quite weird stuff happened. My version was 0.9.1, so I upgraded it to 0.10.0. Your correction still has the appearances of `selectize=FALSE` with the three options availabla, but my original example now has neither `None` option not `Double Quotes (")` option.

Comment: By the way, I've tried it in Linux Ubuntu with R version 3.1.0 and shiny version 0.9.1 (having problems to upgrade it in Ubuntu) and in Windows with R version 3.0.2 and both shiny versions, just in case it is relevant info.

Comment: @Rufo I did have an error in my code. I thought `selectInput` was returning a string but it was actually returning an object. I've updated my code, but it still won't work. The selectize.js library just has no way to allow a blank valued option in the list. The best you can do is use some value like "none" and replace it on the server with "". Or if there is a way, i can't find it. Sorry dude.